# how to grep two paragraph from file?

Tags: grep, sed, awk

i have file "test_file.txt". My output must contains all
"IP  ADDRESS" and "MONTHS OF 2017" from file `test_file.txt`.

```
Server$
Server$cat test_file.txt 
IP ADDRESS:
1. 172.17.17.17
2. 172.17.17.18
3. 172.17.17.19

NEKI TEXT 2
1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five

MONTHS OF 2017:
01.  January   2017
02.  February  2017
03.  March     2017
04.  April     2017
05.  May       2017
06.  June      2017
07.  July      2017
08.  August    2017
09.  September 2017
10.  October   2017
11.  November  2017
12.  December  2017
Server$
```

I found, `egrep` command but output does not contains all 12 Months from file.

```
Server$egrep -A3 "ADDRESS|MONTHS" test_file.txt
IP ADDRESS:
1 172.17.17.17
2 172.17.17.18
3 72.17.17.19
--
MONTHS OF 2017
01. January 2017
02. February2017
03. March 2017
Server$
```

How can I perform command which can have 3 IP address and 12 Months in output?

Comment: super. it works, thank you damadam ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a double `egrep` :

```
egrep -A3 "ADDRESS" test_file.txt && egrep -A12 "MONTHS" test_file.txt
```

Explanation :

`egrep -An`  would match the word (and his line) and take *n* lines under that word thanks to `-A` option

`test_file.txt` is the file that we want to extract these lines

`"ADDRESS"` and `"MONTHS"` are searched word, inside `""` statement

`&&` just execute each command one by one (but if the 1rst didn't work, the 2nd won't be done !)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `awk` in *paragraph mode* (by unsetting the record separator):

```
$ awk -vRS= '/^(IP ADDRESS|MONTHS)/' test_file.txt
IP ADDRESS:
1. 172.17.17.17
2. 172.17.17.18
3. 172.17.17.19
MONTHS OF 2017:
01.  January   2017
02.  February  2017
03.  March     2017
04.  April     2017
05.  May       2017
06.  June      2017
07.  July      2017
08.  August    2017
09.  September 2017
10.  October   2017
11.  November  2017
12.  December  2017
```

Perl has the same functionality:

```
 perl -00 -ne 'print if /^IP ADDRESS/ or /^MONTHS/' test_file.txt
```

Comment: Exactly what I need. :) very useful thank you

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You can use the below command.

```
grep -E "172|01" file.sh
```

The output is as below:

```
1. 172.17.17.17
2. 172.17.17.18
3. 172.17.17.19
MONTHS OF 2017:
01.  January   2017
02.  February  2017
03.  March     2017
04.  April     2017
05.  May       2017
06.  June      2017
07.  July      2017
08.  August    2017
09.  September 2017
10.  October   2017
11.  November  2017
12.  December  2017
```

Explanation:

if you `grep` only for `172` then the output would be

```
$ grep "172" file.sh
1. 172.17.17.17
2. 172.17.17.18
3. 172.17.17.19
```

if you `grep` only for `01`, then

```
$ grep "01" file.sh
MONTHS OF 2017:
01.  January   2017
02.  February  2017
03.  March     2017
04.  April     2017
05.  May       2017
06.  June      2017
07.  July      2017
08.  August    2017
09.  September 2017
10.  October   2017
11.  November  2017
12.  December  2017
```

So you need both of these at once. To search for multiple patterns, we need to use the pipleline metacharacter (`|`) and since this is part of extended regex we need the `-E` option.

To learn more options for the `grep` command, you may find [this article written by me](https://screwlinux.com/how-to-use-grep-command-in-linux/) helpful.

Comment: It won't work if the OP had months of 2016 or 2018 for example, your `grep` would print them also :/

Comment: @damadam Your own answer won't work either if there are more that 3 servers... (I'll give you the benefit of the doubt for the 12 months).